# How can I build regex for an specific format, that works fine in edition

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I have to do a regular expression for this format.

002-251285-0008P

the first three digits are a zone code could be any number but just 3 digit. after and only after I can add "-".
Then the six digits are a date in sets of two digit 25 - day, 12 - month, and 85 - year (the last 2 digits 
 it would be 1985) after that I can add "-".
the last group is another code formed by 4 numero and a letter.

I wanted to checking while a textfield is being edited. but always something shows up.
I will put some of my tries but thing like, "I can add '-' at beginning" or 'it doesn't match until I have the complete format so the textfield is never written'

```
^\$|^([0-9]{0,3})(\\-)?([0-9]{0,6})\$

^\$|^([0-9]{3})(\\-[0-9]{0,6})\$
```

they aren't complete they just the first to group, but or they to strict and don't allow me to enter just numbre o they are to soft and allow me to enter "-" at the start.

every help is appreciated.

**Edit**

Here is how i use the regex

Here I declare all my regex strings:

```
class Regex{
  String regexNumerocondosdecimales = "^\$|^(0|([1-9][0-9]{0,3}))(\\.[0-9]{0,2})?\$";
  String regexSoloLetrasyEpacios = "[a-zA-Z \s]{0,30}";
  String regexSoloNumeros = "^\$|^(0|([1-9][0-9]{0,1}))\$";
  String regexCedula = "r'^\d{1,3}(?:-(?:\d{1,6}(?:-(?:\d{1,4}P?)?)?)?)?\$'";
  String regexLetrasyNumeros = "[a-zA-Z0-9 \s]{0,200}";
  String regexCelular = "^[578] [0-9]{0,7}\$";
}
```

Here I set and validate it

```
abstract class ValidadorString{
  bool esValido(String value);
}

class ValidadorRegex implements ValidadorString{
  final String fuenteRegex;
  ValidadorRegex({this.fuenteRegex});

  bool esValido(String value){
    try{
      final regex = RegExp(fuenteRegex);
      final matches = regex.allMatches(value);
      for(Match match in matches){
        if (match.start == 0 && match.end == value.length) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    } catch (e){
      assert(false, e.toString());
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `r'^\d{0,3}(?:-(?:\d{1,6}(?:-(?:\d{1,4}P?)?)?)?)?$'` or `r'^\d{1,3}(?:-(?:\d{1,6}(?:-(?:\d{1,4}P?)?)?)?)?$'` (with `\d{1,3}` at the start) if empty string is not valid.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong the solution you gave me do the same as `([0-9]{0,3})(\\-[0-9]{0,6})?(\\-[0-9]{0,4})?([a-zA-Z]{0,1})\$`   ?.... and I tried what send, but is there a way that you can forbid "-" and "the letter" in the start?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/zu3dxi/2, this regex does not allow the letter or `-` at the start.

Comment: not so sure what is the problem but when I tried it, in dart it allows me to put the "-" first and allows me to put the letter "d" at the begining... do you know if I should change something to run it correctly in dart?

Comment: Did you use `r` as I showed? `RegExp(r'...')`? `static final RegExp rx = RegExp(r'^\d{1,3}(?:-(?:\d{1,6}(?:-(?:\d{1,4}P?)?)?)?)?$');`

Comment: yes, but i send it into a string, because I re-use the function that validate the format

Comment: I edit the question so you can see how I use it

Comment: I provided the syntax below. Just use `String regexCedula = r'^\d{1,3}(?:-(?:\d{1,6}(?:-(?:\d{1,4}P?)?)?)?)?$';`

Comment: It's not restricting no even a character... and I use just like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
String regexCedula = '^([0-9]{1,3}(-([0-9]{1,6}(-([0-9]{1,4}[A-Za-z]?)?)?)?)?)?$';
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zu3dxi/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([0-9]{1,3}(-([0-9]{1,6}(-([0-9]{1,4}[A-Za-z]?)?)?)?)?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `[0-9]{1,3}` - 1, 2 or 3 digits
  - `(-([0-9]{1,6}(-([0-9]{1,4}[A-Za-z]?)?)?)?)?` - an optional occurrence of:
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `([0-9]{1,6}(-([0-9]{1,4}[A-Za-z]?)?)?)?` - an optional occurrence of:

    - `[0-9]{1,6}` - one to six digits
    - `(-([0-9]{1,4}[A-Za-z]?)?)?` - an optional occurrence of:
    - `-`  -  a hyphen
    - `([0-9]{1,4}[A-Za-z]?)?` - an optional occurrence of 1 to 4 digits and then an optional ASCII letter
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I want playing a bit with regex you gave me, it seems that dart is a bit fussy with the regex, it work like this for me... `^$|^[0-9]{1,3}(-([0-9]{1,6}(-([0-9]{1,4}[A-Za-z]?)?)?)?)?$` if you can edit your answer so I can check it as solution. it would great... Thank you

Comment: @LandyCuadra You should not use `^$|`, just use an optional group around the pattern. `^([0-9]{1,3}(-([0-9]{1,6}(-([0-9]{1,4}[A-Za-z]?)?)?)?)?)?$`

Comment: why shouldn't I?

Comment: @LandyCuadra It is 1) ugly, 2) makes the pattern less efficient, and 3) redundantly longer.